# If the future already exists, why can't we travel to it?

Tags: general-relativity, time, causality, time-travel, observable-universe

since time is actually distance, and if the future already exists, why wouldn't we be able to travel to the future? I understand humanity will never be able to, even if it was possible because our technology will never be as advanced. But if we had any tech. that we wanted, couldn't we theoretically travel into the future by going to a certain point? (Sorry if this is a bad question, I have only studied quantum physics for about a year so I do not know that much about time and GR yet.)

Comment: you are already constantly travelling to the future, just in a relativistically causal way.

Comment: The past is already there, why can't you go back?

Comment: I'm on my way there right now.  Would you like to come along?

Comment: Okay. i get that we can travel into the future, but in a relativistic way. But that was not the context of the question. My question is why can't we travel into the future/past by going to a certain point in the universe. I have gotten multiple answers, ranging from time not being distance, to some random things that are very dumb.

Answer (score 8):

First, time is not distance. This is because of the $-1$ in the metric of spacetime.

Having said that, we *can* travel into the future. We are all travelling into the future at the rate of one second per second. If you want to reach events on Earth beyond your natural lifetime (say 200 years or 1000 years in the future) then you could in principle do so by exploiting time dilation. This requires rocket technology which we don't at present have but it is within the laws of nature.  Another way would be to use some sort of cryogenic method to preserve your body. Again, we don't know how to do it but it is probably possible in principle.

So one can travel into the future in the above sense. What you can't do is travel into the past. So having arrived in the future, you have to stay there. It is a one-way ticket.

Tied in with all this is the question of consciousness itself, and memory and experience. There are a lot of subtle issues here which I won't get into. We use words like "I" and "you" and "now" to refer to certain sets of events in spacetime, but if you look at spacetime as a whole it is hard to know how those events are being singled out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have free will. You can't do anything. You simply exist and there is an illusion that you are doing things. There is an entropy gradient that you exist in. Your memories are only of the past because you can only form memories in the direction that entropy is increasing.

Comment: Wow, that was a real downer. I think I need a drink. Are they serving alcohol in the h_bar?

Answer (score -1):

There are various reasons for the following
1)The laws of physics state that if we travel faster than the speed of the light which is 3*10 to the power 8 we can time travel but it is not possible to the lack of advancements in technology

2)Nobody Disagrees to the non-existence of future but we cant travel
Now let me tell you the answer by relating it to a paradox
The grandfather paradox
According to my understandings, If you somehow travel into the future
and kill your grandfather it arises a question that how will you exist because your grandfather is killed and your father won't take birth and so even you wont
But let me clear that this series of events is going on in other universe which is the multiverse
so when you travel into the future by using a time machine you travel at the speed of light and then reach another universe where the series of events are occuring diffrently
Let's say you are an astronaut on this universe, It is not mandatory that you will be an astronaut
The future of the universe you are living in is undefined.